# Styling react-select, 1px width difference between components

Tags: css, react-select

Regarding [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/):

In certain screen widths, there's a 1px difference in width between `Select-control` and `Select-menu-outer`, respectively the select button container and the select list container. They are siblings and I have applied  `border: 1px solid $gray` style to both of them. I tried to apply that style to other elements but had strange results.

See the 1px glitch:

[image: screenshot 2017-08-10 12 12 10]

They're siblings:

[image: screenshot 2017-08-10 12 13 22]

In a specific scenario, both have a `width: 100%` style applied to it, but `Select-control` has computed width of `183px` and `Select-menu-outer` has computed width of `183.98px` thus the 1px difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Select-control` original width of 183.98 is rounded down (instead of up) because of `display: table`.

I fixed it then by applying `display: table` to `Select-menu-outer` and haven't had any side-effects so far.